# Gaussian process regression model for comparing two groups

Tags: bayesian, gaussian-process, hierarchical-bayesian, functional-data-analysis

I have a data set consisting of functional observations, where $Y_{mi}$ is the response of the $m^{th}$ functional observation from the $i^{th}$ group, $m=1,...,M$ and $i=1,2,$. The observations are on a grid of time values $t=t_1,..,t_k$. I would like to make a model to compare the waveforms from these two groups.

My idea for a model is:

$$
Y_{mi} | \mu,\alpha_i,\theta_\epsilon \sim GP(\mu + \alpha_i, k_\epsilon(\theta_\epsilon)),
$$
with priors
$$
\begin{align}
\mu &\sim GP(0,k_\mu(\theta_\mu)),\\
\alpha_i & \sim GP(0,k_\alpha(\theta_\alpha)),\\
\end{align}
$$
where $k_\mu, k_\alpha, k_\epsilon$ are covariance functions with hyper-parameters $\theta_\mu, \theta_\alpha, \theta_\epsilon$, respectively. The hyper-parameters will have weakly informative prior distributions.

Is this how you would build the model? I've read "Bayesian functional ANOVA modeling using Gaussian process prior distributions", Kaufman (2010), and they use a sum-to-zero constraint on the group effects, but I think a zero baseline parameterization is more natural for the two group case.

**EDIT:**

A second idea, incorporating hierarchical centering reparametrization (Gefland 1999) to avoid nonidentifiability:
$$
Y_{mi} | \eta_i, \theta_\epsilon \sim GP(\eta_i,k_\epsilon(\theta_\epsilon))
$$
with prior
$$
\eta_i|\theta_\alpha \sim GP(0,k_\alpha(\theta_\alpha))
$$

Would this accomplish what I want?

Comment: From description, I got E(Y) = 0. Is it what you want?

Comment: The data does not have a mean of zero. Should I center the process of mu on an approximation of the mean function?